# Using Greasemonkey to add a class to the body of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I use a site that looks like this:

```
    ...
    <body>
    <iframe src="blabla/blabla..."></iframe>
    </body>
    ...
```

The `iframe` loads a different HTML file from the same domain; it has it's own body

In Firebug, it looks like this:

```
    ...
    <body>
    <iframe src="blabla/blabla...">
    ...
    <body class="classname ">
    ...
    </body>
    </iframe>
    </body>
    ...
```

The problem is this: the site would be way easier to view, if I could add a second class name to the second body, like this:

```
    ...
    <body>
    <iframe src="blabla/blabla...">
    ...
    <body class="classname classname2">
    ...
    </body>
    </iframe>
    </body>
    ...
```

I do not own the domain, I just want to 'remix' the web content.

I tried stuff like this:

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name           descr
    // @namespace      http://localhost
    // @description    descr
    // @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
    // @include        http://web.site/sub.ab*
    // ==/UserScript==

    $("iframe").load(function(){
    alert(document.getElementById('frameid').contentDocument);

    });
```

They idea was to use

```
document.getElementById('frameid').contentDocument.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addClass('classname2')
```

But it does not work. Tried the same using `contentwindow`, nothing again. Alert tells me there is a element specified: `[object HTMLDocument]` but when I type anything beyond that, like `.document` the alert becomes empty, or won't show at all.

What am I doing wrong?

*Edit:* Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but I forgot to tell there are actually 2 iframes: one is being blocked by Adblocker, this is why I did not mention this before.

Comment: The sample GM script, in this question, uses jQuery version 1.2.6.  Hopefully that was a typo; recommend you use jQuery version 1.6.2.

Comment: It may be because the frame hasn't loaded yet when greasemonkey is executing, so waiting for iframe's onload could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Greasemonkey it's really easy.  A GM script will fire on an iFrame, much like it would on the containing page.

So, if you create a *second* GM script like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            descr, iFrame handler
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js
// @include         http://IFRAME_SITE.COM/blabla/blabla...
// ==/UserScript==

$("body").addClass ('classname2');
```

It will work with no fuss.

Note that you can do everything with only one GM script, but that can get tricky if you're not careful.  Keep it simple, for now.

Comment: Odd enough the class 'classname2' did not appear in the body element of the iframe, when viewing with firebug, but it DID in the mean body tag.

Comment: Oh, it seems like I messed up the syntax with the include, I fixed that and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `document.body.className += ' classname2';`. You don't have to use jQuery for *everything*, really.

Comment: @porneL: True, but I assume that the script does, or will, do a lot more -- then jQuery will really start to pay off.  Just that one line has shorter and cleaner syntax, already.

Answer (score 0):

`$('iframe').contents()find('body').addClass('className2');`

Comment: Running it directly did nothing. While debuging, alert($c.find('body')); did not respond at all, alert($c) DID respond however.

Comment: alert($c) gives me '[object Object]'

Comment: alert($('iframe').contents()); fires, everything else does not. (i DID try it with and without the dot between contents() and find   It does not work...